# Begin writing a PKCS token on java card

Tags: javacard, pkcs#11, hsm

I want to start implementing pkcs on java card. I have searched a lot but I couldn't find where to begin. I know that a standard token should support PKCS#11 functionalities and probably PKCS#15. should I read those two standards and just do my best to implement them on my card? Is there any open source implementation of PKCS on Java Card?

Regards

Comment: [OpenSC](https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/wiki) seems useful.

Comment: @Abraham I have found OpenSC but it only supports off-card part and it also does not support my card. My problem is on-card application. I found IsoApplet and I built it and installed it on my card, but opensc does returns an error saying "Failed to connect to card: Card is invalid or cannot be handled". now I do not know how to fix it and if my applet is okay!

Comment: Which operation system are you using(Windows/Linux/..)? Can you receive your card's ATR using Opensc-tool (in windows) or pcsc-lite in Linux? The steps are mentioned [here](http://www.pwendland.net/page3/) clearly. Did you use this website too? Maybe you need to add your card's ATR to openSC libraries.

Comment: Adding output of `Opensc-tool -l` and `pcsctest` to the question and also trying with another reader may be useful.

Comment: @Abraham I'm using windows and I have made the steps mentioned in the programmer's website. the output to command " opensc-tool -l " is "openpgp-tool.exe: illegal option". I don't know whether the problem is my card type or sth else!!!

Comment: I have also changed the reader, the problem still remained!

Comment: @Abraham I got the ATR using "opensc-tool.exe -a" what should I do next? :D

Comment: I think I have found the problem! when I type "opensc-tool.exe -n" the result is "Unsupported card" ! can I ask what kind of card do you use, if I can find one @Abraham?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at IsoApplet (that does exactly this) https://github.com/philipWendland/IsoApplet

Answer (score 0):

I found where the problem is! My card is not compatible with OpenSC, as a result there was a problem connecting to my card and make function.

[here](https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/wiki/Supported-hardware-%28smart-cards-and-USB-tokens%29) you can find the list of compatible hardwares.